# R Script fails in Github Actions - can't find cached packages

Tags: r, github, github-actions

In my Github Actions workflow, I am attempting to cache my R packages. Code below:

```
      - name: Cache R packages
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        id: cache
        if: runner.os != 'Windows'
        with:
          path: ${{ github.workspace }}/R/Rlibs
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-${{ hashFiles('.github/R-version') }}-1-${{ hashFiles('.github/depends.Rds') }}
          restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-${{ hashFiles('.github/R-version') }}-1-

      - name: Install dependencies
        if: steps.cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
        run: |
          remotes::install_deps(dependencies = TRUE)
        shell: Rscript {0}

      - name: Run R Script
        run: |
          source("R/script.R")
        shell: Rscript {0}
```

On the first run, the cache doesn't exist yet so the dependencies are installed, and the R script runs successfully. The cache is created at the end of the run.

On the second run, the cache is hit, so dependencies aren't installed from scratch. When the R script is run, it fails when loading the first package, in this case with the line `library(httr)`. It says:
`Error: Error in library(httr) : there is no package called ‘httr’`

I have confirmed that the cache is being created after the first run and then hit on the second run. the httr package is in my `DESCRIPTION` file in the import section, and I can see that it gets installed on the first run. Is there something wrong with my .yaml file or my R script?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by changing my cache path from:

```
path: ${{ github.workspace }}/R/Rlibs
```

to

```
path: ${{ env.R_LIBS_USER }}
```